# Merge sort with ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, merge, compiler-errors

I'm trying to implement a merge sort algorithm for an ArrayList as a parameter. As far as I can tell the code is working fine except for my if statement in the merge method. I'm receiving the error bad operand types for binary operator '<='. I'm sure it is because I have a two incompatible types being compared, but I have seemed to hit a wall figuring that out. Still, a learning student so any guidance or steering in the right direction would be extremely helpful.

I got it to sort now correctly by the last name. Now I'm wondering what I would need to change to sort by first name or even the ID number. If I could get some guidance on how to tackle this I would appreciate it.

```
private static void sortListByID (List<Person> theList) {
   if (theList.size() >= 2) {
      List<Person> left  = new ArrayList<>();
      left.addAll(theList.subList(0, theList.size()/2));
      List<Person> right = new ArrayList<>();
      right.addAll(theList.subList(theList.size()/2, theList.size()));

      sortListByID(left);
      sortListByID(right);
      merge(theList, left, right);
   }
}
private static void merge(List<Person> result, List<Person> left, 
      List<Person> right) {
   int i1 = 0;
   int i2 = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
      if (i2 >= right.size() || (i1 < left.size() && 
            left.get(i1).compareTo(right.get(i2)) < 0)) {
         result.set(i, left.get(i1));
         i1++;
      } else {
        result.set(i, right.get(i2));
        i2++;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `left.get(i1) <= right.get(i2)` only numeric types can be compared using <= operator. what does it mean when a person is smaller or equal to another person??

Comment: Just to point out, I think `Collections.sort()` is a stable merge sort.

Comment: `left.get(i1)` and `right.get(i2)` return an object of type `Person` that cannot be compared using '<='. Person could implement `Comparable` which would allow you to compare the two objects.

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense and I forgot about the fact it is an object, not a primitive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should use `compareTo` instead of `<=` which cannot be used with `Person` objects

```
left.get(i1) <= right.get(i2)
```

becomes

```
left.get(i1).compareTo(right.get(i2)) < 0
```

Make sure the `Person` implements the `Comparable` interface for this method to work

Comment: Thanks! Completely slipped my mind about using the comparable

Answer (score 0):

in completion to the previous answer, you don't need to use a recursive methode to sort a list. this would be the merge-function that merges two lists and sorts them according to your function

You have to implement your own way of figuring out what person comes earlier than another person

```
private static void merge(List<Person> result, List<Person> left,
                          List<Person> right) {
    result.addAll(left);
    result.addAll(right);
    result.sort((o1, o2) -> yourSortFunktionHere...);
}
```